# How do I determine whether a string has non-numbers in it?

Tags: c++, string, parsing, double

I'm making a class called Double that can convert strings to doubles and doubles to strings. I need some way to check to make sure that when the user enters a string, the string doesn't have anything that isn't a number. Some kind of bool function that returns false if the string is all numbers, and true if it has non-numbers in it. So far I have

```
string test;
double d;

cout << "Enter a string: ";
cin >> test;

if(isNAN(test)) //isNAN (is Not A Number)
    cout << "Your entry cannot be converted";
else
{
    Double d1(test); //overloaded constructor takes a string
    cout << "Your string as a double is: " << d1.toDouble() << "\n\n";
}
```

I was thinking making a loop to run though the string and test each char but that seems like a lot of work around. Is there some kind of simple function that can determine whether any part of the string is not a number?

Also, I'm converting it using strstream, somewhat like this:

```
strsteam ss;
string str = "123.45";
double d;

ss << str;
ss >> d;

return d;
```

Would it be easier to check for non-numbers if I convert it first?

Comment: isNAN might be a tricky name, since [NAN has welldefined meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) for floating point number

Comment: Basically I want to make sure that if the user enters something like "hello" or "123abc" it will recognize that it isn't a number and isNAN will return true.

Comment: If you want to know if any character isn't a number, then you need to look at that character. It's not a "workaround" if it's the way things work. Even stringstreams and `strtod` loop through the string and check each character until a non-number or `\0` was hit. In worst case, it'll always be O(n).

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to make sure the entire string gets converted to `double`, i.e. that there is no input left after the conversion. The simple way to verify this is `eof()`:

```
std::istringstream ss( str.c_str() );
ss >> d;

// ss >> std::ws; if you want to ignore trailing whitespace

if ( ss && ss.eof() ) {
    return d; // successful conversion
} else {
    // input left over
}
```

For the lazy, this can be written as a one-liner:

```
double d;
if ( ( istringstream( str.c_str() ) >> d >> ws ).rdstate() == ios::eofbit ) {
```

Comment: It surprised me that the C++ FAQ (see Merlyn's answer) uses `istream::get()` with a dummy char to achieve the same end (no pun intended).  I like you way better than theirs.

Answer (score 2):

To do proper error checking, you can check the result from `ss >> d`:

```
if (!(ss >> d))
{
    // conversion was unsuccessful...
}
```

For a thorough discussion, and complete/generic conversion code, see:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.2

> Would it be easier to check for non-numbers if I convert it first?

With the code provided on that link, it will be just as easy at either point.  You're going to have to do the conversion somewhere, and the conversion code is where you should put the error checking.

As for *where* to put the conversion code, it is a matter of balancing clean class design vs the expected usage of the code.  If the constructor is called a lot, and most users have a string (not a double), then you might consider dirtying up the class and putting the conversion code in the alternate constructor.  Otherwise, let the class worry about what it was designed for, and separate the conversion code from the class.  See:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns

Comment: Wow I feel really dumb. For some reason I was thinking the nonsense I got back when I tried to convert a non-number was actually the string converted. I tried some other entries and I see what I was doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [strtod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtod/).  This function will convert a (C-style) string to a double for you, and will tell you how much of the string was used in the conversion (so you can check to make sure the whole string was a valid number and was parsed).

A bonus is that it's probably faster than using streams (try it!).

Answer (score 0):

I would use something simple and time proven:

```
bool str2f(const char* str, double& d)
{
  return sscanf(str,"%e", &d) == 1;
}
```

It will give you `true` on success and the value itself.

Comment: I don't think this will tell you if the string has bogus content at the end.  For that you might want to add a "dummy" `%c` to the end of the format string (which would then be populated if any excess text is in the string).

Comment: To John Zwinck: that depends on requirements. If you want to get a number from, say, "98 bottles of beer" string and you don't care about the rest then scanf will work for you.

Comment: I agree.  The OP stated, "I need some way to check to make sure that when the user enters a string, the string doesn't have anything that isn't a number."

Comment: Well, yes and no. Something tells me that "anything" here does not include whitespaces or some such. 

At the end, if this `ss << str; ss >> d;` works for him then scanf is closest that he can get.